Optimal balanced ternary set of weights - infinite version
A fairly well known puzzle is to pick the optimal weights for use in a simple, symmetric balance.  It is assumed that any combination of weights with or without the sample will fit in either pan.  The objective is to pick a set which maximizes the range of weights that can be measured.  It must be possible to weigh all integer values.  Binary, $1, 2, 4, 8, ...$ is an obvious choice but $1, 3, 9, 27, ...$ beats it.  For example, you can weigh $2$ by placing $3$ in one pan and $1$ with the sample in the other. With a set of $n$ weights, you can weigh all integer values up to $\frac{3^n -1}{2}$.  It is possible to prove that there is no better solution and no other equally good solution.
Without loss of generality, we can assume that the sample is in the left pan.
You might hope for $3^n$ values as there are that many states of the weights.  Each weight will be off the scales (in neither pan), in the left pan (with the sample), or in the right pan.  However, whether we want it or not, $0$ will be possible (all weights off) and for any positive value, the corresponding negative value (weighing buoyant objects) will be possible (swap all weights from one pan to the other).
I am speculating on a countably infinite version.  So, I want to be able to weigh all positive integer values but, as observed, whether we want it or not, zero and negative values will be possible.
We need to redefine optimal as we obviously need infinitely many weights and all of $\mathbb{N}$ will be as small as any other solution.  So, I will use optimal to mean:

All integer values can be achieved with a finite subset of the weights.

No wasted values - that is no non-integral values.  This is equivalent to saying only integral weights but this seems more in the spirit of the problem.

No duplicates - two different finite subsets must not have the same value.


Powers of $3$ are still a good solution and satisfy these rules.  However, they are not a unique solution.  We can swap $1$ with $4$ or anything else which is equal to $1 \mod 3$.
Obviously, we need at least one weight which is not equal to $0 \mod 3$.
I am trying to prove, or disprove, that there must be exactly one weight which is not equal to $0 \mod 3$.
Let $w_1$ be one of the weights which is not equal to $0 \mod 3$.  Let $S_1$ be the set of values than can be weighed without $w_1$.  $S_1$, $S_1 + w_1$, and $S_1 - w_1$ need to partition $\mathbb{Z}$.  I expect $S_1$ to be all multiples of $3$.  It seems obvious intuitively and it is easy if $w_1 = 1$ but I am finding the general case hard.  I feel that I am missing a simple argument.
Extra detail
If you have swapped $1$ with something else which is equal to $1 \mod 3$.  The other weights are $3, 9, 27, 81, ...$ which is just $3$ times the simple solution.  So, they can match any multiple of $3$.  If your desired weight is a multiple of $3$ then you don't need $w_1$.  If it is equal to $1 \mod 3$ then put $w_1$ in the non-sample pan and now you can balance with a multiple of $3$.  If it is equal to $2 \mod 3$ then put $w_1$ in the sample pan and now you can balance with a multiple of $3$.

@CalvinLin $9$ on one side, $4$ and $3$ with the sample on the other.

Oh thanks, that makes sense. Your extra detail helps. You might want to bold the "I am trying to prove or disprove ..." to make that sentence obvious. $\quad$ Not sure why there's a close vote on this. It's well written and thought through.
